# "Authority URI should have atleast one segment in the path (i.e.https://<host>/<path>/)"...; When Using UCWA2.0 In C#

Tags: skype-for-business, ucwa

We have created an application to send and receive message by interacting with online users in the Skype for business. For achieving this we have followed the below steps, but we are 
facing issue

1. Installed Skype for Business 2016 application
2. Created Azure AD app with "UCWA 2.0" in the Azure. this acts as a user to interact SFB Online users.
3. And gave full delegate access to communicate with SFB online.
4. Generated and error in authority URI "'authority' URI should have atleast one segment in the path (i.e. https:////)"...
5. Later we downloaded the SFB 2015 system app and tried with UCWA 2.0.
6. But facing the same issue with communicating with SFB.